# c++ compilation failure of ambiguity related to implicit conversion

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, boost-any

Try to compile the following code.

```
#include <string>

#include <boost/any.hpp>


class V
{
public:
   V& operator=(int i)
   {
      v = i;
      return *this;
   }
   V& operator=(const std::string& s)
   {
      v = s;
      return *this;
   }
   operator int() const
   {
      return boost::any_cast<int>(v);
   }
   operator std::string() const
   {
      return boost::any_cast<std::string>(v);
   }
private:
   boost::any v;
};


int main()
{
   V v;
   std::string s1 = "hello", s2;
   v = s1;
   s2 = v;
}
```

Below is the error.

```
$ g++ test__boost_any.cpp
test__boost_any.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test__boost_any.cpp:37:9: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} and ‘V’)
    s2 = v;
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/string:52,
                 from test__boost_any.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:668:7: note: candidate: ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
       operator=(const basic_string& __str)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:718:7: note: candidate: ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:736:7: note: candidate: ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
       operator=(basic_string&& __str)
       ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Implicit conversion operators are seldom a good idea.

Comment: For your use-case I would rather use a simple templated `get` function. As in `template<typename T> T get() const { return boost::any_cast<T>(v); } const` And with that said, modeling classes as just holders of data might be useful for some designs and use-cases, but I'd argue that modeling classes on behavior is better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that may be so, but this still seems like a legit question.  Why is the `char` version being considered when it requires *two* conversions?  `V`->`int`->`char`

Comment: fwiw, you do not need any boost for this https://godbolt.org/z/YsMd7aEqK

Comment: @MarkRansom Because `char` can be initialized from an `int` value, and `V` is convertible to `int`. So its really just 1 conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` has overloaded `operator=`s that accept `char` and `std::string` as input, and `int` is implicitly convertible to `char`.  Your `v` object is convertible to both types, so the compiler doesn't know which `operator=` overload to call, hence the ambiguity. So you have to explicitly tell the compiler which type you want to convert `v` to so it then knows which `string::operator=` to use.

Comment: Doesn't the implicit conversion make the `char` overload a worse match than than `string`?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using conversion operators, there are two *user defined conversion sequences* at play here (via conversion functions [link to relevant standardese](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv#fct)). Neither is ranked higher than the other ([link to relevant standardese](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#2)). The only way to disambiguate is to perform a cast to the desired type:

```
s2 = static_cast<std::string>(v);
```